# How can I rotate my API key for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I wasn't thinking and committed my project I'm starting to GitHub with my API key in one of my files. According to Google themselves, this isn't inherently dangerous itself but my concern is someone malicious could grab my key and use it in their project, potentially hitting limits on the free plan very quickly. I'm struggling to find out how I can grab a new key, any help? Below is a code snippet of what I exposed.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.8/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "my-key",
    authDomain: "my_domain",
    databaseURL: "my_db_url",
    projectId: "my_project_id",
    storageBucket: "my_storage_bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "my_sender_id"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some of these keys can be regenerated from the Firebase console, other keys (such as `databaseURL`, `projectId` and `storageBucket`) can't be regenerated. You will have to create a new project to get all new keys.

Comment: Got it. Luckily I'm only in the early stages so I can do this, but if someone made this mistake deep into their project they'd be hosed. Are there any plans to allow these to be rotated in the future?

Comment: As you saw in other answers, there are not authentication credentials, but configuration data. Since the users of your app need this data for their app to be able to access the Firebase project, any malicious user can always get the exact same configuration data from the app.